# What does "spec" mean in Javascript Testing

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, tdd

I'm fairly new to the Javascript world (coming from Android) so I've been reading up on how to setup Mocha/Jasmine to get my test environment in place.  I've noticed a convention of "spec" in reference to test directories, file suffix, suite names, and/or tests/assertions.

Is this specific to testing in Javascript?  And what does "spec" actually stand for?  Specification, Expectation, or ?

Comment: specification (meaning test file).  was idiomatic in jasmine I think.

Comment: It's loosely a way of writing tests, as a specification (or set of expectations) rather than a more assertive style. Related to the BDD fad.

Comment: So, would you say this is/should be a common standard for all test files I write?

Comment: @tschaka1904 I think it's ultimately a matter of preference and project consistency. If you work on an existing project using a specific convention then you should stick with that. If you are starting from scratch then it should be a team decision. If you are by yourself then I personally go with what my framework uses, again for consistency.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Spec is short for "Specification" as @DavinTryon suggested above.

Specification in terms of a test refer to the technical details of a given feature or application which must be fulfilled. The best way to think of this is as the technical specifications for a given unit of code to pass successfully. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  I like to use common conventions with whatever technologies I'm using at the moment but want to understand the meanings behind them.

Comment: Makes sense. Glad to have helped.